# Count all Items with conditional group by date

Tags: mysql

I have a data like below

```
| 2015-10-01 00:18:55 | 100021397    | canceled           |
| 2015-10-01 02:05:16 | 100021398    | processing         |
| 2015-10-01 02:15:23 | 100021399    | processing         |
| 2015-10-01 02:17:40 | 100021400    | processing         |
| 2015-10-01 02:28:02 | 100021401    | processing         |
| 2015-10-01 02:31:39 | 100021402    | processing         |
| 2015-10-01 02:44:13 | 100021403    | canceled           |
| 2015-10-02 00:00:35 | 100021519    | canceled           |
| 2015-10-02 01:05:22 | 100021520    | processing         |
| 2015-10-02 01:06:42 | 100021521    | processing         |
```

I need the output to group by date with format

```
Date         | Number Of all Item  | Number of Item with status not canceled |
2015-10-01   |       7             |          5
2015-10-02   |       3             |          2
```

Create the first two column is quite easy, however the third column is a bit tricky, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `SUM()` you can "count" the results of boolean expressions (which return 0 or 1, false or true).

```
SELECT DATE(date), COUNT(DISTINCT item), SUM(status != 'canceled')
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  
  date(`date`) as `date`, 
  count(*) as `Number Of all Item`, 
  sum(if(status!='canceled',1,0)) as `Number of Item with status not canceled`
from tbl1 group by date(`date`)
```